# Semantic UI grid column height

Tags: html, css, semantic-ui

I am building a simple grid based layout where I want to place `.vertical pointing menu` inside the 3th purple row, as show [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uw9op8sc/1/). Which would be the right way to make the height of the 3th row occupy the 100% of the viewport? I tried by setting the body and pointing menu heights to 100%, but that didn't work. The height of that row is determined by the height of the content, in this case the menu's height.

Answer (score 13):

The following code snippet (and jsfiddle) is taken from the [Semantic-UI Issues](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/1959) page, where the same question was asked by the same user:

```
<style>
    html, body {
        height: 100%;
    }

    .ui.grid {
        height: 100%;
    }
</style>

<div class="ui padded equal height grid">
  <div class="two wide purple column">
  </div>
  <div class="fourteen wide stretched column">
    <div class="ui equal height grid">
      <div class="sixteen wide red column"></div>
      <div class="eight wide orange column"></div>
      <div class="eight wide blue column"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ea04tkwo/

Comment: @Jan Thanks for the answer, however how can I make the left pane scrollable, `overflow-x: auto` doesn't seem to work.